# Saving an unlimited amount of AVAudioRecorder files

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

The program I'm working on requires me to save a large amount of AVAudioRecorder files for future use. However, while I am aware of how to save and record a static amount of files, I want to be able to save them dynamically without having to use the same sound file URL (like "sound.caf") every time a recording takes place, as well as be able to play those files whenever I need to. Does anybody know how I would go about doing this?

The code below shows my current recording code:

```
- (IBAction)playSound:(id)sender {

    if (!self.audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        NSError *error;

        if (self.audioPlayer)
            self.audioPlayer = nil;

        self.dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                            NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.docsDir = [self.dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        self.soundFilePath = [self.docsDir
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

        self.soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.soundFilePath];

        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                       initWithContentsOfURL:self.soundFileURL                                    
                       error:&error];

        self.audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", 
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        else
            [self.audioPlayer play];
    }

}


- (IBAction)recordSound:(id)sender {

    if(!self.audioRecorder.recording)
    {

        self.dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                       NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        self.docsDir = [self.dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
        self.soundFilePath = [self.docsDir
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

        self.soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.soundFilePath];

        self.recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                        dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                        AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                        AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                        AVSampleRateKey,
                                        nil];

        NSError *error = nil;

        self.audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                              initWithURL:self.soundFileURL
                              settings:self.recordSettings
                              error:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            [self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
        }


        [self.audioRecorder record];
        [self.audioRecorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 5];
        [self.record setTitle:@"Stop" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else if (self.audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        [self.audioRecorder stop];
        [self.record setTitle:@"Record" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    } 
    else if (self.audioPlayer.playing) {
        [self.audioPlayer stop];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approch this if I understand your question correctly.  I have an app which records sound snippets and stores them for later playback.  I'll share my approach and you can take it or leave it.

Initially I create a recorder much like you do though I use the temporary directory (NSTemproraryDirectory) rather than NSDocuments.  I use a single file in this temp location for recording then after recording has finished and the user confirms a desire to save the recording I load the temp file's data into memory with [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:] and write it out to a path of my choice using [FileManager createFileAtPath:].  There may be a more efficient way to reproduce the file but this is efficient enough for my purposes.

For the path passed to createFileAtPath I use a string built of my recording storage folder and a uniqueID string generated for each recording.  I use [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString] to create the unique ID but you could use a hash or any other technique which makes sense for you so long as you are sure it is unique within your set of recording IDs.

I can then create an AVAudioPlayer for any recording I have an ID for just by building the path as I did when I saved it.  If one has not kept track of IDs in a list or database one could enumerate the recordings directory and build a list of recording ID's from their file name.  I use a database to store the ID along with metadata such as recording time, length, subject etc.